# App crashes on backgrounding because of SimpleAudioEngine

Tags: iphone, background, cocos2d-iphone, multitasking, simpleaudioengine

So I׳m trying to play some effects in my Cocos2D game using SimpleAudioEngine , but after I have added them my app crashes when it goes to background (multitasked).
I searched for this problem in the internet but all the solutions that I found didn't work for me. What I did find out is that this problem happens because my app is somehow trying to play sounds when backgrounded.

In console it shows me (which is the same error I found other people had):

> sgx error (background gpu access not permitted):

And another thing, when I run my app on the simulator, or even on my device while debugging carefully (going line-by-line with XCode while the app is running) this doesn't happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was experiencing this, on about 25% of the occasions that my application re-entered the foreground. Like you, when I removed the sounds, the problem went away. That is how I came across your question here.

I *may* have found a solution to this. I have made what appears to be an unrelated change, but the problem seems to have gone away. Now, when my app enters the background, I invalidate my main scheduled timer. When my app re-enters the foreground, I then re-schedule the timer (after reloading my sounds, which I completely shut down on entering background).

So far, the problem has not come back. I would be interested to know if this helps.

Answer (score 2):

I just had this issue. I resolved it by having a bool to check if the app is running or in background that I set to true when the app goes to foreground ( applicationWillEnterForeground ) and that I set to false when the app goes to background ( applicationDidEnterbackground ) . So using the bool you can tell if the app is in the background and if it is, I just exit out of drawView function in EAGLView (thus not doing any graphics rendering which was causing the error).

I am a very dodge programmer but that method has worked for me and I hope it works for someone else. I did not need to unload and reload my sounds or anything and my app now has Multitasking XD

Comment: UIApplication seems to have a property applicationState that provides this information as well. This is iOS4+ only, though, so a check with "respondsToSelector:" is in order.

Answer (score 1):

I just resolved this issue on my end. Here's what was wrong in my case and, from what I can tell from the other answers and comments on this page, many other people's case as well:

By default, when I started my project, *CCDirector::sharedDirector()->pause();* and *CCDirector::sharedDirector()->resume();* were both being called twice, once by **(void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)** and **(void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)** respectively in **AppController.mm**, and once by **AppDelegate::applicationDidEnterBackground()** and **AppDelegate::applicationWillEnterForeground()** respectively in **AppDelegate.cpp**.

**Make absolutely sure** that these methods are only being called once, in AppController.mm. In AppDelegate.cpp, instead make sure that you are calling *CCDirector::sharedDirector()->stopAnimation();* in place of *CCDirector::sharedDirector()->pause();* and *CCDirector::sharedDirector()->startAnimation();* in place of *CCDirector::sharedDirector()->resume();*.

Hope that's helpful to anyone else stuck in this crappy situation!

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure it's related to audio? "background gpu access" sounds like it's using OpenGL.

Comment: Yep, many people on the Internet said that this problem happened to them because of audio, and when I remove the effects it doesn't happen.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue in my application and spent some 4 hours to find out. Going background was OK the first time, but crash application the second time. With a short error message related to OpenGL. I had the same questions: how audio can crash graphics. But it wasn't a question of audio, but a question of notifications...

I discovered that going foreground was creating 2 timers in my custom level meter class.
I had registered **UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification** and **UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification**. Then, going background invalidated only one, since I registered only on notification... That was it!

One need's count its notifications!